# What should the asymptotic covariance matrix be?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is $n\times 1$ and $a$ is scalar. They are random quantities such that
$$
\operatorname{E}\left[\begin{pmatrix}a\\X\end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad\operatorname{Var}\left[\begin{pmatrix}a\\X\end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{aX} \\ \sigma_{Xa} & \Sigma_X\end{pmatrix}\tag{$*$}
$$
where $\sigma_a>0$, $\Sigma_X$ is positive definite, and $\sigma_{Xa}$ ($n\times 1$) is the transposition of $\sigma_{aX}$.

Suppose that $(a_t,X_t)$ are i.i.d. $\sim (a,X)$ for $t=1,\ldots,T$. Then, as $T\to\infty$,
$$
\sqrt{T}\left(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^TX_ta_t-\sigma_{Xa}\right)\overset{L}{\to}N(0,V).
$$
Here, $\overset{L}{\to}$ denotes convergence in distribution. It seems  $V$ should be
$$
\operatorname{Var}(Xa)=E(a^2XX')-\sigma_{Xa}\sigma_{aX}
$$
and it doesn't seem that ($*$) has enough info to evaluate $E(a^2XX')$. But I'm not confident in my understanding. So my question is:

> What should $V$ be? What if we add the fact that $(a,X')'$ is jointly normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $V$ is the variance of $\sqrt{T} \left( \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_t a_t - \sigma_{Xa}\right)$, which is the variance of $Xa$ by the scaling and additive properties of variance, and you do not have the information to evaluate it.

In the normal case, you can use [Isserlis's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem).
$$E(a^2 X X') = E(a^2) E(X X') + 2 E(a X) E(a X') = \sigma_a^2 \Sigma_X + 2 \sigma_{Xa} \sigma_{aX}$$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that theorem. Is there any chance please you could supply a close-form formula, in the case of normality, for $V$ in terms of $\sigma_a,\sigma_{Xa}$, and $\Sigma_X$?